# SoundCloud Error (clang failed with exit code 1)

Tags: objective-c, ios, soundcloud

I'm trying to impement SoundCLoudApi from [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI), but there is clang error without any description:

```
Ld /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/scapitest.app/scapitest normal i386
    cd /Users/dimakorolcenko/Documents/SoundCloudIssues/scapitest
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Intermediates/scapitest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/scapitest.build/Objects-normal/i386/scapitest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSONKit/JSONKit /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libJSONKit.a /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libOAuth2Client.a /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libOHAttributedLabel.a /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSoundCloudAPI.a /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSoundCloudUI.a /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth2Client/OAuth2Client /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SoundCloudAPI/SoundCloudAPI /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SoundCloudUI/SoundCloudUI -framework CoreText -framework CoreGraphics -framework Security -framework CoreLocation -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/dimakorolcenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scapitest-dbwrumaigeiklgcvrmtokdvcppfu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/scapitest.app/scapitest

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have completed all steps from instruction, but it doesn't work. I have no ideas, how to solve it. Please, help me to find solution. May be it is more common error, and it is not SoundCloud issue...

Comment: Is this an iOS app? Looks like you've set your deployment target to OS X 10.6.

Comment: Check your header search paths.  What do they say?

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment target is probably wrong.

Select your project in the project navigator on the left side. Go to the build settings tab. Make sure your deployment target is iOS, not OS X.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed `SoundCloudAPI.framework` and `OAuth2Client.framework` (which is only for mac os x) from my iOS app.